# What is the correct way to run ZF application under url sub-folder under Apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, base-url

This is probably a common question but I couldn't find an answer to it.

I have a PHP application using Zend Framework. Say we I run the application under `my-app` host and the source files are located under `/my-path/my-app` in local file system. Below is the Apache vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName my-app
DocumentRoot "/my-path/my-app/public"
<Directory "/my-path/my-app/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `.htaccess` file in `public` directory contains following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

So far, all standard for ZF applications.

Now, I need to run this application under an url sub-folder (for example `foo`), i.e. under `http://my-app/foo/` instead of `http://my-app/`.

What do I need to change to make this work? What is the best practice?

Assume that generating URLs with the base-url from the application is not a problem. And also assume that the application will rewrite all URLs including the links for css/js sources for the application.

Thanks!

Comment: This may help you try changing RewriteRule ^.*$ /foo/public/index.php [NC,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after playing with it a bit I found the easy solution. All is needed is just to add an alias in the Apache vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName my-app
DocumentRoot "/my-path/my-app/public"
<Directory "/my-path/my-app/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /foo /my-path/my-app/public

</VirtualHost>
```